# api.derive.crowdloan.contributions: Expected hex value to convert, found '0x'

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama, api, crowdloan, kabocha

Context:

I'm trying to fetch datas from an ended crowdloan.
The crowdloan is on kusama, for parachain id 2113.

I first connect:

```
async function connect() {
    let endpoint = config.endpoint;
        global.endpoint = endpoint;
        const provider = new WsProvider(endpoint);
        const api = await ApiPromise.create({
            provider,
            ...spec
        });
        return api;
}
```

then fetch the addresses of the users that contributed:

```
async function fetchCrowdloan() {
    try {
        const api = await connect();

        console.log(await api.derive.crowdloan.contributions(2113))
        process.exit(0)
        // other stuff
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
```

Yesterday, when i ran my script, an array of the 478 users i expected to be here, was logged in the terminal. I closed my PC, went to sleep, and this morning, it doesn't work anymore, I get this error:

```
2022-06-23 12:27:51        RPC-CORE: getKeysPaged(childKey: PrefixedStorageKey, prefix: StorageKey, count: u32, startKey?: StorageKey, at?: Hash): Vec<StorageKey>:: creat
eType(StorageKey):: Expected hex value to convert, found '0x'
2022-06-23 12:27:51             DRR: createType(StorageKey):: Expected hex value to convert, found '0x'
Error: createType(StorageKey):: Expected hex value to convert, found '0x'
    at createTypeUnsafe (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs/create/type.js:73:18)
    at TypeRegistry.createTypeUnsafe (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/@polkadot/types/cjs/create/registry.js:333:46)
    at /home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core/cjs/bundle.js:395:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at RpcCore._formatInputs (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core/cjs/bundle.js:395:19)
    at callWithRegistry (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core/cjs/bundle.js:252:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core/cjs/bundle.js:266:9)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
    at /home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
    at Object.errorContext (/home/erudyx/work/rusty-crewmates/polkadot/kusama-crowdloan-snapshot/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
```

Was there an update in the api of kusama in the night ? How can i solve it ?

Update: all of the other calls are working fine, it's really just the `contribution()`function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was identified as a bug.

See:

- https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4981
- https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/pull/1567

There is nothing wrong on your side. Wait for the fix to land and upgrade your @polkadot/api to a newer version.

Comment: Yep, i ended up asking on github, i'm glad they solved it so fast !

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me (`"@polkadot/api": "^8.8.3-9"`):

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

export const fetchCrowdloan = async () => {
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io');
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
    console.log(await api.derive.crowdloan.contributions(2113))
    console.log((await api.derive.crowdloan.contributions(2113)).contributorsHex.length)
}
```

Output:

```sh
{
  blockHash: '-',
  contributorsHex: [
    '0x0034622b3c63b574024d395c25c8e516c0b5d2761d0601d2545cc76f17435801',
    '0x020fa85efa96a432e05598df7ec297921a457cf8a2a7600b92760939d9b9400d',
    ....
  ]
}
478
```

Comment: I still have the same error using your code, your version and your endpoint... What env are you using ? How do you install/start the script ?

Comment: install the packages and run the script*

Comment: or maybe its a yarn version thing

Comment: Bruno what versions are you using? I am getting same problem as erudyx, maybe because i am adding fetchCrowdloan() to call the function, perhaps i need to await or i am calling it incorrectly?